# Localize installer with VS setup and deployment project?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I want to localize my installer but in Visual Studio 2008, Localization Property drop down does not contain the language. I think we could use code page but if users don't want to change locale in Region and language in their computers, characters will display wrong. I've read the article at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/10/05/msi-databases-and-code-pages.aspx, it said that MSI unofficially support UTF-8 but I'm not familiar with MSI. Have anyone experienced, please point me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio offers only a small number of languages for package localization. If you want a language which is not in the list, you can try using a different setup authoring tool which supports it.

Answer (score 0):

My requirements is similar, but not the same.
I want that my custom setup recognized the language of the OS and visualized all the messages in this language.
A possible workaround may be to insert a dropdown which has all my languiges, but i really don't know how.